# Rails console scrollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have two developer machines, running the same version of Rails and Ruby. One machine has scrollback functionality that survives exit and console restart. The other machine forgets everything on exit. Any idea why this is happening? How can I get a persistent scrollback buffer on my other machine?

Comment: Can you give us some more details? What OS, and which rails version?

Comment: Sure:

iMac:
OS X 10.5.8
Rails 2.3.4
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0]

Macbook:
Rails 2.3.4
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-03-13 patchlevel 0) [i686-darwin8.11.1]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the [wirble](http://pablotron.org/software/wirble/) gem installed on one machine and not the other.

Comment: I doublechecked, and no wirble gem on either machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have irb history enabled on one machine and not the other?

http://macdevelopertips.com/ruby/ruby-irb-command-history.html

You may have a ~/.irbrc and a ~/.irb-history file somewhere on the machine that is keeping history.